# Javascript keyword THIS and ELEMENT

Tags: javascript

```
if( !sky.containers ) sky.containers =
{
        Window : function()
        {
                this.element = document.createElement("div");
                this.element.modal = false; 
                this.element.height = 240;
                this.element.draggable = true;
                this.element.resizable = true;
                this.element.position = "center";
                this.element.width = 240;
                this.element.target = document.body;
                this.element.title ="";
                this.element.headerHeight = 30;;
                this.element.effects = {};
                this.element.show = function()





                return this.element;

        }}
```

What is the keyword THIS in this context?"sky.containers" or "Window"?And what is ELEMENT,if theres no variable define whit this name?

Comment: Try doing a console.log(this) or alert(this) to get more details on 'this'.

Comment: Don't use alert, use console.log, especially in Chrome or FireFox (with FireBug) which gives more verbose output.  Alert is less informative.  You can see the 'console' in those browsers w/ F12

Comment: `this` is `Window` in this context. However, the `this` inside `show()` refers to `show` and not `Window`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Window() is a constructor function.  That means it gets called when you create a new object with something like

```
var myWin = new Window();
```

Inside the function, `this` will refer to the new object that was just created.  (And which gets assigned to `myWin` in the above example call.)

As for 'element', it's a property of the newly-created object.  It doesn't exist until this line:

```
this.element = document.createElement("div");
```

Which creates a new <div> element and assigns the DOM representation of it to the property.

Comment: Except that from the function, `this.element` is returned.  Seems like that breaks its functionality as a constructor, so `myWin` would contain the new div element, not a Window object.

Comment: "this.element.modal","this.element.width" only works beacuse modal and width  are properties of previous DIV DOM element created...right?

Comment: @Michael - no.  the return value of the constructor doesn't affect the return value of the `new` call.

Comment: @ozsenegal: you can create any property you want on any javascript object.  Think of `foo.bar = 1;` as you would assigning to a hash or array in another language; in JS it is, in fact, the same as doing `foo['bar'] = 1;`.